# jquery-ui datepicker maxdate - possible to reset it inside onSelect?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

Can maxdate attribute be reset inside the onSelect delegate?

It would be perfect if I could do something like:

```
 $(".date-picker").datepicker({

        maxDate: someDate,

        onSelect: function (date) {

            if(somecondition is true) {
               maxDate = someotherDate;
            }

            //some other functionality goes here, 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', [value]);
```

To reset the original value, you'll want to store that value somewhere and simply reuse the above code with that original value where appropritate.

Comment: And how would I reset maxDate within onSelect then? simply by doing maxDate=newMaxDate.toString()

Comment: what is option? Please keep in mind that I need onSelect (I am doing other stuff in it).

Comment: It's just a method which allows you to change options post-initialization. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker

Comment: Can I set maxDate to null with the above code?  essentially need to remove it for some date pickers.